# Interest of Androig Log in released APK

Tags: android, logging, apk

I have read from http://developer.android.com/reference/android/util/Log.html that :

"Verbose should never be compiled into an application except during development. Debug logs are compiled in but stripped at runtime. Error, warning and info logs are always kept.".

I understand the interest of logging while programming for debugging.

So what is usage of Log.i() Log.w() and Log.e() into a released application ?
If an error occures, i don't own the target device to connect it on my PC and get logs.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think anyone should use logging in released applications. Logging is costly and it will slow down the application. Even if you can use logging data some how (sending them periodically over internet) it's not a efficient way. To see how your apps behaves after production use Google Analytics.